# how to translate dataset to some other language

Tags: c#, multilingual

i m building a multi-lingual website. static text i am translating using resource files. but dataset which i m to bind with dropdownlists, i don't know how to translate that. i have tried google transllate but it give me too many languages. i only need 3 or 4 langs. please help me in this regard

Comment: how do you fill the dataset ?

Comment: what do you want to translate? Caption (en:salutation => de:Anrede) ? content (en:"Dear Mr. " => de:"Sehr geehrter Herr ")?

Answer (score 1):

One standard practice is to have description tables including a language field

So if you now have

```
Products:  ProductId, Description, Price, ...
```

You will have to change to 2 tables like

```
Products:     ProductId, Price, ... 
Description:  ProductId, LangCode, Description
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have 1 translation table

Columns:

TableId (The table that needs translation)

FieldId (The field in the table, there can be more than one field that needs translation)

Language (The Language to translate into)

Key (The value of the primary key in the table )

Value (The translate value for field )